# How can I both sort multirelationships in laravel and also get out the latest of deepest child

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am creating a movie series database and have models like so:

```
Series
  $with=["seasons"]
  hasMany(App\Seasons)

Season
  $with=["episodes"]
  belongsTo(App\Series)
  hasMany(App\Episode)

Episode
  belongsTo(App\Season)
```

#### Question 1

How can I based on Eloquest Series::all() sort desc by Episode ID ?

```
[
  [...
    seasons: [
    [...
       episodes: [
          [id]       <---- sort by this
       ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

#### Question 2

Can I based on same relations get just the latest episode of each season in each series?

Thanks

Comment: sort what by episode id?

Comment: @lagbox I want to sort Series desc based on episode id

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:**

Yes. When you are building your Season eloquent model, you need to define your relationship and can also apply sorting rules and more at the same time:

```php
public function episodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Episode::class)
            ->orderBy('episodes.created_at');
}
```

**Question 2:**

Yes. You can create a new relationship query like in my first answer and add the `->limit(1)` call. You can do much more than this. Be sure to check out the [Laravel Relationship docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I have checked the docs but couldn't get my head around the multiple steps-part. 
Your answer sets orderBy on the relation itself meaning this will always happen. What if I just want to do this for certain routes? like api/series shall order by created_at asc and api/series/latest order by created_at desc ? or as Question 2 limit in a seperate route for example, thanks!

Comment: `public function latestEpisodes() { return $this->hasMany('App\Episode')->orderBy('episodes.id', 'desc');}`  this works with `return Series::with('seasons.latestEpisodes')->get();` for episodes, but I cannot sort seasons desc here.. how do I do something like this `Series::all()->with('series.latestSeasons')`

Comment: I figured it out with `return Series::with('latestSeasons')->get();` :) but now only the episodes get sorted, I want the series to be sorted based on episodes. Like if Series 2 have a newer episodes than Series 1 and 3, Series 2 will be shown first in the array.

Comment: Well, this could get a bit complicated, but I have no better idea than this: The hasMany Method only returns a query builder. So you can do the same stuff like you would do in SQL to reach that goal. In SQL it's probably a good idea to have a sub query which returns all series of a season sorted by their newest episodes. So you can join that sub-query for the orderBy statement in your relationship. Try to build it as plain SQL and then try to implement it into your relationship query builder.